# Why the error occurs in fancytooltips? -- Extraneous floating text and JavaScript Debugger pops up

Tags: texworks, fancytooltips

---

Description:

Why the error occurs in fancytooltips? -- Extraneous floating text and JavaScript Debugger pops up.

---

Detailed Description:

I want to add a new tooltip when mouse over the text. Thus, I use the fancytooltips package

and do the following step in "Detailed Steps" section.

However, It does NOT work as expected. There are extraneous floating text in .pdf and a
window with title "JavaScript Debugger" pops up, saying such as "SyntaxError: syntax error 1:Field:Mouse Enter SyntaxError: syntax error 1:Field:Mouse Enter".

(for more details, see the figures at bottom of "Detailed Steps" section.

### I don't know why

Detailed Steps:

Step 1:

Downloaded the package.

I downloaded fancytooltip.zip package from its official website to directory "Downloads".

Then I unzip it to directory "Downloads" with 7-zip.

Step 2:

Read the docs then follow the instructions.

I had read the docs then follow the instructions. To follow the instructions, I had downloaded "Adobe Acrobat".

Step 3:

Test.

I had verify the behaviour and examples of fancytooltip works as expected, to a bunch of files "tooltipy" "fancytooltips-example" respectively, through the following way

First check the original behaviour of code provided by fancytooltips works as expected.

`open <filename>.pdf with "Adobe Acrobat"`

Clear the buffer so that when compiling .tex with pdfLaTex mode not cause error.

`close <filename>.pdf`

`open <filename>.tex with TeXworks`

According to Ch.2 section 1in the docs of fancytooltips, .tex file must be compiled with pdfLaTex. Otherwise, either compiler will raise error, or generated .pdf is malformatted.

`change compiler mode to pdfLaTex`

`compile it (NOTE that at compile time with pdfLaTex mode, one has to click enter at the bottom of console until either there are errors or pdf displays.)`

See the result.

`open <filename>.pdf with "Adobe Acrobat"`

`close <filename>.pdf`

Before changing code in .tex file, I doing so to files "tooltipy", "fancytooltips-example" respectively, it works as expected.

For tooltipy,

I add the following statement in tooltipy.tex (and, of course, save it),
compiling it with pdfLaTex mode.

```
\strankaB{reference}{At}
```

And open tooltipy.pdf with "Adobe Acrobat", I find that there exists a tooltip with text At
, which works as I expected.

For fancytooltips-example,

I add the following statement in fancytooltips-example.tex (and, of course, save it),
compiling it with pdfLaTex mode.

```
\begin{definition}
This is Reference of  \tooltip{reference}{3}. 
\end{definition}
```

and change the following statement:

`\usepackage[filename=tooltipy,movetips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}`

to

`\usepackage[filename=pics/tooltipy,movetips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}`

The reason why I do so is before changing the statement, the compiler will raise error which indicates that the tooptipy.pdf is NOT found, with the following error.

`!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file tooltipy.pdf): cannot find image file to oltipy.pdf`

However, I open fancytooltips-example.pdf with "Adobe Acrobat", I see a window with title "JavaScript Debugger" pops up, and the there are extraneous floating text in fancytooltips-example.pdf. (Shown as Fig.2)

(For original result, see Fig.1)

(For result after change code, see Fig.2)

Fig.1:

[image: Original Content of tooltipy.pdf]

Fig.2:

[image: Content of fancytooltips-example.pdf after changing code]

---

Appreciation:

Any replies will be appreciated.

---

Code:

For tooptipy.tex,

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[czech]{babel}
% \usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\parindent 0 pt

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}
\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.7, 0.7, 1}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.7, 1, 0.7}

\usepackage{multido,graphicx}
\usepackage[papersize={5in,5in},margin=1pt]{geometry}
\long\def\stranka#1#2{
\setbox0=\hbox{\begin{minipage}{2in}
\fboxsep 0 pt
\color{red}
\shadowbox{{\fboxsep 4pt\colorbox{yellow}
    {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \color{black}#2
    \end{minipage}}}}
\end{minipage}\ \ \ \ }
\pdfpagewidth=\wd0
\pdfpageheight=\ht0
\advance \pdfpageheight by \dp0
\copy0
\keytip{#1}
  \newpage
}

\long\def\strankaB#1#2{
\setbox0=\hbox{\fboxsep 0 pt
\color{red}
\shadowbox{{\fboxsep 4pt\colorbox{yellow}
    {\color{black}#2
    }}}}
\pdfpagewidth=\wd0
\pdfpageheight=\ht0
\advance \pdfpageheight by \dp0
\copy0
\keytip{#1}
  \newpage
}


\def\definice#1{
  \begin{center}
    \colorbox{gray}{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth} #1
      \end{minipage}}
  \end{center}
}
\def\vyuziti#1{
  \begin{center}
    \colorbox{lightblue}{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth} #1
      \end{minipage}}
  \end{center}
}
\def\vypocet#1{
  \begin{center}
    \colorbox{lightgreen}{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth} #1
      \end{minipage}}
  \end{center}
}


\begin{document}

\stranka{derivace}{ \definice{The \textbf{derivative} is the limit
    $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h,$$ if this limit exists as a finite number.} \vyuziti{ The derivative
    has important applications in physics as a rate of change and as a
    linear approximation.}  \vypocet{The derivative can be evaluated
    using appropriate formulas}}

\stranka{hodnost}{ \definice{\textbf{Rank} is a maximal number of
    linearly independent rows in a matrix.}  \vyuziti{Rank can be used
    to prove or disprove linear independence of vectors and it also
    appears in the Frobenius Theorem.}  \vypocet{To find the rank of a
    matrix, you have to convert this matrix into row echelon form.}}

\strankaB{definition}{???}


\pdfpageheight=0pt

\pdfpagewidth=0pt

\def\obrazek#1{%
\setbox0=\hbox{\color{red}%
    \fboxsep 0 pt{\shadowbox{{\color{black}\includegraphics[width=3.5in, 
        page=#1,viewport= 0 57 350 230,clip]{tecna2.pdf}}}}}
\pdfpagewidth=\wd0
\pdfpageheight=\ht0
\advance \pdfpageheight by \dp0
\copy0
\newpage}


\multido{\i=1+1}{25}{\obrazek{\i}}

\end{document}
```

For fancytooltips-example.tex,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftex,designiii]{web}

\usepackage[filename=tooltipy,movetips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}

\let\rmdefault\sfdefault

\usepackage[shadein]{shadethm}

\newshadetheorem{definition}{Definition}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{bkg}{rgb}{1,0.9,0.9}
\def\Message#1{\colorbox{bkg}{
      \begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
        \smallskip
      #1
        \smallskip
      \end{minipage}
 }}
\begin{document}


\parindent 0 pt

\Message{
\begin{itemize}
\item Use Acrobat Reader or Adobe Acrobat to view this file, please.
\item The blue texts are covered by an active button. If you \textbf{move mouse over} one of
  these buttons, tooltip appears. If you move your mouse out or if you
  close the page, the tooltip disappears.
\item The first links are tooltips, the fifth one is animated tooltip.
\item The tooltips appears with the left down corner at the mouse
  cursor, or at least as close as possible. 
\end{itemize}
}

\begin{definition}
  This is definition of  \tooltip{rank}{2}. 
\end{definition}


\begin{definition}
  This is \tooltip{definition}3 of \tooltip{derivative}{1}. Filler
  text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text. Filler text.
  \tooltip{derivative}{1}.
\end{definition}


% \begin{definition}
%  This is Reference of  \tooltip{reference}{3}. 
% \end{definition}

This is a geometric \tooltipanim{idea}{4}{28} which is behind the
definition of derivative.

\end{document}
```

---

Ref:

About fancytooltips:

For fancytooltips official website,

[fancytooltips official website](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips)

For fancytooltips official docs,

[fancytooltips docs](https://ctan.mirror.twds.com.tw/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancytooltips/fancytooltips.pdf)

---

IDE:

```
TeXworks
MikTex Console.
```

---

Compile mode:

```
pdfLaTex
```

---

View with:

I view .pdf with

```
Adobe Acrobat
```

---

Comment: Welcome! You're violating the licence by redistributing modified files without renaming: "You must not distribute the modified file with the filename of the original file." (https://ctan.org/license/lppl1.2 condition 3) It is, in any case, a bad idea to modify package files without renaming them, even when it's permitted.

Comment: Note I would try to help you, but the tooltips aren't even expected to work on Linux, so all I'll see are the icons.

Comment: your example can't be tested as you are using a local tecna2.pdf.  The miktex package is faulty: it doesn't install the fancytipmark.pdf. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/415. If I correct that and use example-image-duck instead of `tecna2.pdf` your example works fine and doesn't produce a java script error for me.